# Spring Data REST + JPA remove from OneToMany collection [not owner side]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Currently we have an issue (a well known one) with `Spring Data JPA` + `Spring Data REST` (`Hibernate` as `JPA` implementation) when trying to update the collection (relation) which is a not the owning side.

The mapping is the following:

```
@Entity(name = Product.NAME)
public class Product {
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "baseProduct", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Variant.class)
List<Variant> getVariants() {
...
```

and on the other variant side:

```
@Entity(name = Variant.NAME)
public class Variant extends Product {
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Product.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "baseproduct_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
Product getBaseProduct() {
...
}
```

all is **good** on the **Java** side if you use `Spring Data JPA` only, however if you want to update the "product" by updating its collection of variants and send `PATCH` request to https://localhost:8112/storefront/rest/product/21394435410197232 containing the payload of the new collection only (having 2 out of the 3 items):

```
{"variants":["22801810293768080","22801810293768096"]}
```

I get no exceptions or anything but since the owning side is the other side nothing is persisted and I got the old `3 items` again.

I `know` that I can fix this by setting

```
@JoinColumn(name = "baseproduct_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
```

on **both sides** and not use `mappedBy` anywhere, however I have heard there is a performance implication which I am not sure how big it is (we got 100+ entities having `@OneToMany`) and I wonder is there better workaround via `@PreUpdate` listener or something ?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have this exact problem, how do I update the association from non-owner side?

Comment: as explained bellow if it is bidirectional then you need to update both sides.

Answer (score 7):

You have to synchronize both sides of the bidirectional association, and also add on `orphanRemoval` and `Cascade`.

So, your mapping becomes:

```
@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "baseProduct", 
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
    targetEntity = Variant.class
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
    orphanRemoval = true)
List<Variant> getVariants() {
```

And the two add/remove methods:

```
public void addVariant(Variant variant) {
    getVariants().add(variant);
    variant.setBaseProuct(this);
}

public void removeVariant(Variant variant) {
    variant.setBaseProuct(null);
    this.getVariants().remove(variant);
}
```

You need to implement [`equals`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/) and [`hashCode`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/) methods in the `Variant` child entity for the `add` and `remove` methods to work effectively.

Comment: Thanks, however currently I don't want to remove the orphans I just want to remove the "connection" not removing any of the side :) Also I am not a huge fan of cascade(s) and maybe I am missing something but the addXXX and removeXXX methods will be invoked by Spring Data Rest somehow ?

Comment: Then you have the wrong mapping because you haven't specified a `@JoinTable`. If you have a join table, then the best way to map it is to map the join table as an intermediate entity which has 2 `@ManyToOne `associations. I have an example in my book, [High-Performance Java Persistence](https://leanpub.com/high-performance-java-persistence).

Comment: @VladMihalcea  WIth this solution I get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null. I have a list of elements for which I have to invoke removeVariant method for every list item... How to solve this problem? I tried with iterator.remove() but so far without success:(